# What is causing my QueueVec const Head() function to behave strangely?

Tags: c++, queue, constants

I have to implement my own QueueVector library for an exam and I'm having a problem with a call to a const function. This function has the same body of the non-const version but it behaves weirdly when called on an empty queue.

Here are the functions of my library which are causing the problem:

```
template<typename Data>
QueueVec<Data>::QueueVec() {

  size = 8;
  vec = new Data[ size ]{};

}

template<typename Data>
const Data & QueueVec<Data>::Head() const {

  if ( !Empty() ) {

    return vec[ front ];

  } else {

    throw std::length_error("Object is empty");

  }

}

template<typename Data>
Data & QueueVec<Data>::Head() {

  if ( !Empty() ) {

    return vec[ front ];

  } else {

    throw std::length_error("Object is empty");

  }

}

template<typename Data>
bool QueueVec<Data>::Empty() const noexcept {

  if ( countElements == 0 ) {

    return true;

  } else {

    return false;

  }

}
```

And here is my code which tests these functions. Note that the code here below is simulating what my teacher's test does.

```
template<typename Data>
void HeadTestHelp( const lasd::Queue<Data> & que) {

    cout << "Const Head" << endl;

    try {
        que.Head();
    } catch(length_error e) {
        cout << "Object is empty" << endl;
    }

}

template<typename Data>
void HeadTestHelp( lasd::Queue<Data> & que) {

    cout << "Non-const Head" << endl;

    try {
        que.Head();
    } catch(length_error e) {
        cout << "Object is empty" << endl;
    }

}

template<typename Que>
void HeadTest( Que& coda ) {

    HeadTestHelp( coda );
    HeadTestHelp( (const Que ) coda );

}

void Mytest() {

    lasd::QueueVec<int> queTest; //Calls default constructor

    HeadTest(queTest);

}
```

Output is like this:

```
Non-const Head
Object is empty
                //ERROR: Here the code goes on loop and never ends
                //instead of printing
                //"Const Head
                //Object is empty"
```

As you can see, in the Head() function const and non-const versions have the same body but behave differently. Not only that, but the const version doesn't seem to work at all on an empty queue. I've done several tests and it works perfectly when queue is not built with default constructor.  Why is that? What can I do to fix that?

EDIT: Here below you can find the whole hpp of the class in case you need it. Just note that this class is a component of a more complex hierarchy(which is why there are a lot of methods marked as override).

```
#ifndef QUEUEVEC_HPP
#define QUEUEVEC_HPP

/* ************************************************************************** */

#include "../queue.hpp"
#include "../../vector/vector.hpp"

/* ************************************************************************** */

namespace lasd {

/* ************************************************************************** */

template <typename Data>
class QueueVec : virtual public Queue<Data>,
                 virtual protected Vector<Data>{
                  // Must extend Queue<Data>,
                  //             Vector<Data>

private:

  // ...

protected:

  // using Vector<Data>::???;

  using Container::size;
  using Vector<Data>::vec;

  // Vector<Data>::size = 8;

  unsigned long front = 0;
  long rear = -1;
  unsigned long countElements = 0;

  // Data* queueVector;

  // ...

public:

  // Default constructor
  // QueueVec() specifier;

  QueueVec();

  /* ************************************************************************ */

  // Specific constructor
  // QueueVec(argument) specifiers; // A queue obtained from a MappableContainer

  QueueVec( const MappableContainer<Data> & );

  // QueueVec(argument) specifiers; // A queue obtained from a MutableMappableContainer

  QueueVec( MutableMappableContainer<Data> && );

  /* ************************************************************************ */

  // Copy constructor
  // QueueVec(argument);

  QueueVec( const QueueVec & );

  // Move constructor
  // QueueVec(argument);

  QueueVec( QueueVec && ) noexcept;

  /* ************************************************************************ */

  // Destructor
  // ~QueueVec() specifier;

  virtual ~QueueVec() = default;

  /* ************************************************************************ */

  // Copy assignment
  // type operator=(argument);
 
  QueueVec & operator=( const QueueVec & );

  // Move assignment
  // type operator=(argument);

  QueueVec & operator=( QueueVec && ) noexcept;

  /* ************************************************************************ */

  // Comparison operators
  // type operator==(argument) specifiers;

  bool operator == ( const QueueVec & ) const noexcept;

  // type operator!=(argument) specifiers;

  bool operator != ( const QueueVec & ) const noexcept;

  /* ************************************************************************ */

  // Specific member functions (inherited from Queue)

  // type Head() specifiers; // Override Queue member (non-mutable version; must throw std::length_error when empty)

  const Data & Head() const override;

  // type Head() specifiers; // Override Queue member (mutable version; must throw std::length_error when empty)

  Data & Head() override;

  // type Dequeue() specifiers; // Override Queue member (must throw std::length_error when empty)

  void Dequeue() override;

  // type HeadNDequeue() specifiers; // Override Queue member (must throw std::length_error when empty)

  Data HeadNDequeue() override;

  // type Enqueue(argument) specifiers; // Override Queue member (copy of the value)

  void Enqueue( const Data & ) override;

  // type Enqueue(argument) specifiers; // Override Queue member (move of the value)

  void Enqueue( Data&& ) override;

  /* ************************************************************************ */

  // Specific member functions (inherited from Container)

  // type Empty() specifiers; // Override Container member

  bool Empty() const noexcept override;

  // type Size() specifiers; // Override Container member

  unsigned long Size() const noexcept override;

  /* ************************************************************************ */

  // Specific member function (inherited from ClearableContainer)

  // type Clear() specifiers; // Override ClearableContainer member

  void Clear() override;

protected:

  // Auxiliary member functions

  // type Expand() specifiers;

  void Expand();

  // type Reduce() specifiers;

  void Reduce();

  // type SwapVectors(arguments) specifiers;

};

/* ************************************************************************** */

}

#include "queuevec.cpp"

#endif
```

Comment: can you provide a code that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: The code that I used to test the library and that I already shared is what causes the error. There is not much more useful code outside of this, I think I put every function involved in the issue, you just have to code a main which calls MyTest() and it's done.
 Is there something else that I should add?

Comment: Isn't your output right? You call 'HeadTestHelp' twice, so u should get Non-Const and then const head.

Comment: In the output part I said that the code loops when the program has to print the const part. This means that the program just never ends and this obviously isn't what I want and what I expect from that call, which is what I called a weird behaviour.